# Kineticist with Telekinetic Blast, Telekinetic Haul; and Improvised Throwing in general

Tags: pathfinder-1e, improvised-weaponry

So in a Pathfinder game I'm in, I'm playing a telekineticist and I'm looking to using Telekinetic Haul for the sake of convenience. One other nice feature is the ability to throw significantly larger and heavier objects.

If I decided to use a significantly large or heavy object such as an armchair, a table, a bookcase, and so on, how would I best calculate damage dice? While I ask in context of the kineticist, this could be more broadly spread across most improvised weapon options.

Addendum: Rereading Telekinetic Blast I see it says that it always does damage "as a one-handed improvised weapon for a creature of your size" (assuming improvised or nonproficient in the weapon), which closes off one of my inquiries.

Comment: "...which closes off one of my inquiries."  I only see one question.  Can you please clarify what question(s) you are asking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Telekinetic Haul cannot cause damage.

[Telekinetic Haul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Telekinetic-Haul) allows you to move heavy objects and at a faster rate, but does not increase the damage of your [Telekinetic Blast](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Telekinetic-Blast), nor does it modify *Basic Telekinesis* (it's prerequisite ability) so it can now cause damage.

[Telekinetic Haul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Telekinetic-Haul) is basically an upgrade of [Basic Telekinesis](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Basic-Telekinesis), and is also an upgrade to the weight limit on your *Telekinetic Blast*.

> Telekinetic Haul
>
> Element(s) aether; Type utility (Sp); Level 2; Burn 0
>
> Prerequisite(s) basic telekinesis
>
> When using **basic telekinesis**, you can move an object that weighs up to 100 pounds per kineticist level you possess. When using your **telekinetic blast**, you can throw an object weighing up to 100 pounds per kineticist level you possess, but **this doesn't increase the damage**.

[Basic Telekinesis](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Basic-Telekinesis) says:

> Basic Telekinesis
>
> Element(s) aether; Type utility (Sp); Level 1; Burn 0
>
> **This ability is similar to mage hand**, except you can move an object that weighs up to 5 pounds per 2 kineticist levels you possess (minimum 5 pounds), and you can move magical objects.

[Mage Hand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mage-hand), as we know, does not cause any damage. Thus, Telekinetic Haul cannot be used (by itself) as an attack.

[Telekinetic Blast](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Telekinetic-Blast), on the other hand, does cause damage, but the weight of what you can throw at someone is limited to *5 pounds per kineticist level you possess*. If you also learn *Telekinetic Haul*, this weight limitation is increased to *100 pounds per kineticist level you possess*.

It will also increase the duration of your [Basic Telekinesis](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Basic-Telekinesis) from *concentration* to *1 minute per kineticist level you possess*, if you accept one point of Burn, that is.

### Telekinetic Blast

[Telekinetic Blast](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Telekinetic-Blast) is your main attack as an *Aether Kineticist*, and all your abilities will work on or modify this ability. So you will be looking at Wild Talents that improve your Telekinetic Blast, or your *Blast* in general.

Your *Blast Damage* is physical, which means you will hit on a ranged attack and deal:

- **1d6 plus Con modifier plus 1d6+1 per 2 kineticist levels**.

> Alternatively, you can loosen the strands of aether in order to deal damage to both the object and the target **as though you had thrown the object yourself** (instead of dealing your normal blast damage).

This means that you are only using the ability to "levitate" the object against your target, not using it's full power to cause damage. So it doesn't modify how you throw objects, which are normally improvised weapon and you take a -4 penalty to the attack. For weapons, you cause the weapon's damage plus your Strenght modifier.

Now, the ability goes further and say:

> You substitute your Constitution modifier for your Strength modifier if throwing the object would have added your Strength modifier on the damage roll, and you don't take the –4 penalty on the attack roll for throwing an object that wasn't designed to be thrown. In this case, the object's special effects apply (including effects from its materials), and if the object is a weapon, you must be proficient with it and able to wield it with one hand; otherwise, the item deals damage as a one-handed improvised weapon for a creature of your size.

So, we replace the Str modifier by your Con modifier, remove the penalty from the attack roll, and finally, if the object is a weapon, it will deal the weapon's damage, otherwise it deals damage as a [one-handed improvised weapon for a creature of your size](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#TOC-Improvised-Weapons). So a medium kineticist could deal from 1d3 to d18 damage according to the *weapon's table*, at GM's discretion.

> To determine the size category and appropriate damage for an improvised weapon, compare its relative size and damage potential to the weapon list to find a reasonable match.

Personally, the ability does seem weird. But if you think about it, on the alternative use, your are simply improving your own thrown damage. While with the main use, you are hurling it using your powers.

The alternative use sounds like you have the option to "look like" you threw it yourself instead of the object magically flying against the target. The intent here doesn't sound like it was supposed to cause more damage then the primary's effect, but an alternative that behaves differently.

Comment: That makes sense. And having reread Telekinetic Blast, I note that it specifies always dealing damage as an improvised one-handed weapon for a creature my size thus rendering my original question moot. Regarding improvised hurling in general, would you be able to provide a bit further information as to how damage dice can be calculated if you are able to hurl something of much greater size and weight than expected?

Comment: As a GM i would say that, even though you are hurling something bigger, it doesn't have the proper speed to increase the damage. Bigger rocks will move slower than smaller ones, thus the damage remains roughly the same.

Comment: Honestly, what causes the damage is the power behind the hurl (the aether), not the object by itself. Otherwise this object would also take damage from the impact.

Comment: Fair enough on the former regarding damage dice. 

On the latter comment I was more referring to the second part of Telekinetic Blast where object and target would take damage (as replicated as well with Foe Throw) with larger objects. But I had missed the limitation in that paragraph.

Comment: Also, a correction, your telekinetic blasts cause your Blast Damage (as seen on the Kinetic Blast class ability), which is 1d6 + 1/2 your CON + 1d6 per 2 Kineticist levels for *physical blasts*.

Comment: So a 3rd level kineticist character with 18 con would cause 2d6+2 with his telekinetic blast.

Comment: Not quite. It's a physical blast, not an energy blast, and thus does 1d6+1+CON, increasing by 1d6+1 per 2 levels.

But what I was asking was related to this sentence: "Alternatively, you can loosen the strands of aether in order to deal damage to both the object and the target as though you had thrown the object yourself (instead of dealing your normal blast damage)."

Comment: That is correct, i mixed the two.