# Can the kineticist's Telekinetic Haul wild talent be used to drop heavy objects on targets?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, kineticist

I was watching an anime in which a minor character attacks by lifting large objects and dropping or throwing them at people, and I wanted to replicate that in *Pathfinder*.

According to the answer to the question [Kineticist with Telekinetic Blast, Telekinetic Haul; and Improvised Throwing in general](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92632/kineticist-with-telekinetic-blast-telekinetic-haul-and-improvised-throwing-in/), the damage of the throw is determined by your blast damage unless you treat it like a throwing attack, and the weight is limited to 5 pounds per 2 levels so that won’t help.

But what if I instead used Telekinetic Haul to drop say a boulder on top of my enemy’s head? That’s going to hurt *a lot*. The real question is whether I can lift it vertically to a significant enough degree. If it’s something like a boulder, even a foot above my target’s head should be more than enough to deal more damage than a blast.

Can Telekinetic Haul be used to drop objects on people’s heads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Yes, a Kineticist can use Telekinetic Haul to drop objects on creatures.

As usual in Pathfinder 1E, it's complicated because it involves multiple interacting rules.

First let's consider how far Telekinetic Haul can reach, and how heavy the hauled object can be. The maximum weight carried by [Telekinetic Haul](https://aonprd.com/KineticistTalentsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Telekinetic%20Haul) equals 100 or 1000 pounds per Kineticist level.

> When using basic telekinesis, you can move an object that weighs up to 100 pounds per kineticist level you possess. [...] If you accept 1 point of burn, the maximum weight increases to 1,000 pounds per kineticist level you possess and the duration increases to 1 minute per kineticist level you possess.

The maximum range is limited by the [Basic Telekinesis](https://aonprd.com/KineticistTalentsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Basic%20Telekinesis) talent, which normally has Close range (25 ft + 5 ft per 2 Kineticist levels).  If you have the extended range and extreme range talents, this can increased to Medium (100 ft + 10 ft per Kineticist level) or Long range (400 ft + 40 ft per Kineticist level).

> This ability is similar to mage hand  [...] If you possess the extended range wild talent, you can increase the range of basic telekinesis to medium range and increase the rate of movement to 30 feet per round, and if you possess the extreme range wild talent, you can increase the range of basic telekinesis to long range and increase the rate of movement to 60 feet per round.

According to the environmental rules for [falling objects](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/environment/environmental-rules/#Falling_Objects), the damage dealt by (and to) a falling object is based on the object's size.  It's not clear how to calculate an object's size based on its weight, so that would be up to the GM.

> `Table: Damage from Falling Objects`
> `Object Size  Damage`
> `Small        2d6`
> `Medium       3d6`
> `Large        4d6`
> `Huge         6d6`
> `Gargantuan   8d6`
> `Colossal     10d6`

The object's material and falling distance (up to 150 ft) also affect the damage dealt. Additionally, intentionally dropping an object on a creature requires a ranged touch attack. If the Kineticist succeeds on this attack roll, the target may get a Reflex save to reduce the damage further.

> Objects made of lighter materials might deal as little as half the listed damage, subject to GM discretion. For example, a Huge boulder that hits a character deals 6d6 points of damage, whereas a Huge wooden wagon might deal only 3d6 damage. In addition, if an object falls less than 30 feet, it deals half the listed damage. If an object falls more than 150 feet, it deals double the listed damage. Note that a falling object takes the same amount of damage as it deals.
>
> Dropping an object on a creature requires a ranged touch attack. Such attacks generally have a range increment of 20 feet. If an object falls on a creature (instead of being thrown), that creature can make a DC 15 Reflex save to halve the damage if he is aware of the object.